# Running and "hiding" PostgreSQL portable in Java on Windows

Tags: java

I'm writing an app which will be fully portable. I decided to use PostgreSQL portable for persistence. I launch it from Java like this:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime
                .getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[] { "C:\\PATCH\\PostgreSQLPortable-9.3.exe" });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that command prompt (console) shows up. I need to start it without any trace. Not even launching it and closing fast, more like running in background.  Is it possible somehow?

Comment: I don't know anything about Postgres portable, but usually `pg_ctl.exe` is used to start the database server. And if I do that from the command line it does not have a console window attached with it

Comment: Look on apache commons exec it solves lot of common things with invocation from Java.

Comment: Use an embeddable database for that... Like H2, Derby, HSQL, ...

Answer (score 0):

Java does not has out of the box support to execute applications in such a manner, however [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/index.html) can be used to install particular exe as a service and start, and when you exit from your application you can stop and delete the service.